# Error when retriveing output from dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Tags: oracle, ddl, dbms-output

When I have tried to run the following SQL statements I'm getting the error:

```
 set long 90000
set heading 999
set lines 100
select 
   dbms_metadata.GET_DDL(u.object_type,u.object_name,'MY_SCHEMA')
from  
   dba_objects u
where  
   owner = 'MY_SCHEMA'
   AND OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE';
```

Error:

> ORA-31600: invalid input value CHAIN for parameter OBJECT_TYPE in function GET_DDL 
>   Funktion GET_DDL ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", Line 6069
>   ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", Line 8666 ORA-06512: in Line 1
>   31600. 00000 -  "invalid input value %s for parameter %s in function %s"
>   *Cause:    A NULL or invalid value was supplied for the parameter.
>   *Action:   Correct the input value and try the call again.

Can you please give some advice how I can retrieve the select output.

Comment: also, why not just query user_tables - dbms_metadata is an expensive pkg to call, no need to give it an expensive query to feed it as well

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#BGBIEDIA

List of possible object type parameters. And not all elements from the list are equal to dba_objects.object_type. You have to translate it to appropriate value.
In your case problem is `chain` object. Generally for any scheduler object, object type is `PROCOBJ`. But i don't know if it will work for chains.

`select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCOBJ','chain_name') from dual;`

Comment: Why is it looking at CHAIN at all when the object type is filtered on TABLE?

Comment: I don't think so that the code in question caused the exception. The first line of exceptions says that input value of `OBJECT_TYPE` was `CHAIN`